# ng-repeat not working for option tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have array of city which is available on first select ng-change which I like to show in second option list;
But it does not show there.

In angular controller

```
mainApp.controller('addUserCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

   $scope.getCities = function() {
      $scope.citieslist = ["Nagpur", "Pune", "Latur", "Aurangabad"];
   };

});
```

Select in HTML

```
<select ng-change="getCities()" ng-model="state" required>
  <option value="Bihar">Bihar</option>
  <option value="Chhattisgarh">Chhattisgarh</option>
  <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
</select>

<select name="city" required>
  <option ng-repeat="city in citieslist">{{ city }}</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: in my case it is working perfectly, can you post your error

Comment: Sorry. But with this edited its not working.. after ng-change

Comment: As you can see in this plunkr, it 's working fine. https://plnkr.co/edit/1qSbV0LAWA23CLVRLRUL?p=preview

Comment: @Olezt the same is not working in my code :(. even I just copied from plunkr. after ng-change it show the array in console as well.

Comment: Try to create a plunkr that reproduces your problem, otherwise we can not help you.

Comment: @PrashantFepale check my answer

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
<select ng-repeat="city in citieslist" name="cityList" required>
<option >{{ city }}</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('addUserCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.citieslist = ["Nagpur", "Pune", "Latur", "Aurangabad"];
     $scope.getCities = function() {
       $scope.citieslist = $scope.citieslist;
     };
  });
```

Try to use this code, you have assign a list inside `getCities()`, it will work at `ng-change="getCities()"` but can't assign value at `ng-repeat`. so you need to assign it out side method then you can assign it again inside method, then it will work. check the code in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/adGIedlHeHCr3kUro7SZ?p=preview)

Comment: Why would you even do something like this? Now citieslist is already defined and ng-repeat populated.

Comment: i think when <select ng-change="getCities()" ng-model="state" required> then it is working fine, but when he try to use in ng-repeat it is unable to do 2 way binding. so for resolve this i have 1st declare the array. if it is wrong then please comment

Answer (score -2):

Change dropdown html code like below

```
<select name="citys" ng-repeat="city in citieslist" required>
  <option>{{ city }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Putting the `ng-repeat` on the `<select>` will repeat the `<select>` causing there to be multiple dropdowns.

Comment: I think simply some people making downvote for me,, because same answer gave by other person no downvotes for them..